# A 2d array data structure to efficiently erase and append rows and columns at back and front?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure in c++ which allows to store a 2d array with the ability to efficiently erase a number of rows or columns at the front (left or up) or at the back (down or right) of the 2d grid. I know one could hack together such functionality by using nested vectors. However, [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) points out that erasing at any position other than the back of the vector is inefficient.
Is there a better data structure choice for this purpose? If so, which one is it?

Comment: How important is insert/delete vs iteration and access? Which can you afford to make expensive in order to make the other fast?

Comment: @user4581301 Equally important, I'd say. Day to day application would involve continuous erasure/addition of new rows and columns, along with write and read in the same program cycle.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) maybe?

Comment: You could use a multidimensional `std::deque`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, I'll give it a try!